# Apartment numbers in Greece

Tags: greece, mail

How are apartments numbered in Greece? Are they labelled at all?

I know in some countries they are numbered, in some they are done by floor or position (Portugal/Spain), and in some (Germany) the system relies on the name of the occupant.

Would you put a building name in an address, similarly to the UK? Or would the apartment number go after the building/house number?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  Do you want to mail something to Greece and want to know the format of the address?

Comment: @PeterM Not sending actual mail, just helping to sort a list of residential addresses for my job. I'm trying to standardise things so that addresses are broken into constituent parts and can then be reassembled in the correct order if they are required in a contract we send out. This is an attempt to future-proof the system in case we get an address in Greece for someone who lives in an apartment.

Comment: So it's not really a travel question, but a data storage question?

Comment: @PeterM No, it's not really a data storage question. I am asking how a Greek address would look if it referred to an apartment. If this is the wrong exchange for this, then a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not necessarily the wrong forum here, but your use case for needing it comes across as not being a travel related subject, but rather as an Information Theory question.  As it's sort of GIS related, https://gis.stackexchange.com might be a better fit, but I am unfamiliar with what is OK to ask on that SE

Comment: I think if you ask your question on [gis.se] as suggested by @PeterM, including and focusing on the info you provided in your comment above about the addresses being broken into constituent parts etc., you might get an answer, and I think it should be on topic (while it might not be about GIS software specifically, it's about storing what is essentially geographic information in a database, which is what a GIS does).

Comment: @Midavalo GIS person here, I'm not sure this is about *storing* data. I think this has more to do with country specific rules about address formatting. It could be about how to properly write an address on a postcard for all we know.

Comment: @Berend I'm just following on from PeterM's suggestion to post it on [gis.se]. From the OP's comment about breaking the address down it sounds similar to how an address system would be broken down in a GIS. I'm just saying I would consider it on topic there.

Comment: If you're attempting to build a global service, I would strongly recommend you forget trying to break down addresses and just accept freeform text.  Indian, Japanese, Chinese, Thai etc addresses are wildly different from Western conventions, often lacking things like street names or house numbers.

Comment: See also: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Comment: I think EU has some classification (and handling slit and merge of apartment), but that std is not for addressing, but for infrastructure (phone, fiber, electricity cabling): nobody else know the "cabling address". There is also a ID of apartments (unique number), but again: nobody know it. Wrong data is much worse then missing data.

Comment: There's a [bizarre range](http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/) of rules and conventions around Europe with some places not regularly using apartment numbers (e.g. Germany) and others having different formats and abbreviations. Weirdly, I can find examples for almost everywhere except Greece.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about standardizing Greek addresses, not travel.